# Children of layout not expanding to fill height

Tags: material-design-lite

I'm trying to use the whole of the window, and hope that the picture below is the fastest qay to describe the situation.  The problem is that I can't get `.mdl-grid` below to expand to fill its parent container(`height:100%` does not work). All of the parents are marked `height:100%`, and the immediate parent (`mdl-layout__content`) does fill out the view window. The one thing that might help is the `mdl-layout__content` has `display: inline-block`?

[image: How to expand mdl-grid]